# Can I use a vent that was over an electric oven for a dryer instead?

Tags: kitchens, vent, dryer

I just bought an apartment built in 1980 and it does not have a washer and dryer.  There is a vent above an electric oven.  I am remodeling the kitchen and moving the oven to the other side of the kitchen and would like to put a stackable washer dryer in the same place where the oven is.  This way I can use the vent for my dryer only.  Please let me know if I can do this and if it is safe to do so (and following the safety/state code in California-OC).

It is more important for me (and it increases the market value of my home) to have a washer/dryer than to be worried about the smell of fried onion or garlic once in a while in my home.  I would just open the windows instead of having a vent on top of my stove.

Please advise! This is very important improvement for me and makes my life much much easier to have my own washer/dryer in my home.

Comment: Many range hoods do not vent outdoors:  they just blow air around the room a bit.  A few are claimed to have filters but I have never seen one.  Are you sure your hood actually vents outdoors?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is a good solution.

There are a couple of potential issues:

Most dryer vent hose is 4" diameter, some oven vent is 6", so you might need an adapter

The other aspect that may need to be addressed is the louvers on the outside.  Be sure you dryer exhaust is strong enough to open the louvers or you may have to replace it for one with lighter duty springs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue that I can see with repurposing a vent.  Dryer vents are usually 4" diameter, stove vents are 5".  Make sure the line is clean and the screen and damper outside is still in good functioning condition.  A "recirculating" range hood will be needed, if you install one.

The real issue is whether you are allowed to remove the stove vent, they are sometimes required by local building code.  You cannot combine the stove and dryer into one vent (they must have separate outlets)

You should be able to ask your local building official this question.  It is very likely you'll need a building permit for this work, possibly several.  Again, your local building official/permit office can tell you if a permit is required.  Not having a permit for remodeling work can affect future sale of the property.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would check for is how the vent was constructed, specifically whether any screws were used to join different sections of the vent. While it is probably ok to use screws for HVAC/exhaust fans, it is a very bad idea for dryer vents since lints get caught on the screws creating a fire hazard.